# How to get (or create) tags at GitLab?

Tags: c#, gitlab, gitlab-api

Gitlab version: 13.3.1

I user c# library [github](https://github.com/nmklotas/GitLabApiClient) and try to create tags:

```
var client =  new GitLabClient("https://gitlab.domain.local/", "key");

        var projects = await client.Projects.GetAsync();
        var tagsProject=projects.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id ==25);
        //var tags = await client.Tags.GetAsync(tagsProject,"test");

        await client.Tags.CreateAsync(tagsProject,new GitLabApiClient.Models.Tags.Requests.CreateTagRequest("created test tag","master","message","release descriptions text")); //error
```

But i have error:

```
'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
 <title>404 Not Found</title>
 </head><body>
 <h1>Not Found</h1>
 <p>The requested URL /api/v4/projects/user_name/tags-test-project/repository/tags was not found on this server.</p>
 </body></html>'
```

What i do wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you!

P.S. i try to use curl:

```
curl https://gitlab-ci-token:old_token@gitlab.domain.local/api/v4/projects/25/repository/tags
```

and it returns OK and show tags.

Comment: GitLab tends to return 404s when you try to do something you're not allowed, like accessing a project you're not authorized to access. Are you sure your client has the right permissions to create a tag?

Comment: i grand all permissions (scopes) to token: api, read_api, read_repository, write_repository.

Answer (score 0):

I should use:

```
var client = new GitLabClient("https://gitlab.example.com", "your_private_token");
var tags = await client.Tags.GetAsync("group/project");
var tags = await client.Tags.GetAsync(25); //25 is project id
var tag = await client.Tags.CreateAsync("group/project", new CreateTagRequest(...))
```